# Logger 'django_request' unable to be configured

Tags: django, heroku

After getting a `collectstatic error`, I ran the command `heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and I got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
'%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
```

This is my `manage.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_test.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn django_test.wsgi
```

And the `LOGGING` section of `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
         'django.request': {
             'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
             'level': 'ERROR',
             'propogate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

In `Procfile`, I tried replacing `.wsgi` with `.app` but I only generated an `ImportError` and I researched my error online but I still don't know why I'm getting the `ValueError` or how to fix it. Also, I was wondering if I need an Apache server to get my Django site to be able to work or will Gunicorn suffice? I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this explains the 'Unable to add handler' error message, but you have spelled `propagate` incorrectly. I've made the same spelling mistake before, it took at least an hour before I spotted the problem.

Comment: It doesn't explain that message but thank you for the spelling correction.